# Connect to mongodb on centos7 docker image

Tags: bash, mongodb, docker

i am new with docker (1 day) and i want to make an image with the full env for new people.

So i just installed mongodb on my image:

```
RUN echo $'[mongodb-org-3.2] \n\
name       = MongoDB Repository \n\
baseurl    = https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/ \n\
gpgcheck   = 1 \n\
enabled    = 1 \n\
gpgkey     = https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.2.asc' > /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo
RUN yum install -y mongodb-org
```

But when i run it with `sudo docker run -t -i myimage  /bin/bash` and try to start mongo with `systemctl start mongod` i got this error:

Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to create customized version of Mongo DB docker images? If not, you can use already existing mongo DB image in the docker repository.

If you just want to have only mongo DB in docker, you can just run it with

```
docker run mongo
```

This will download mongo image from repository. Otherwise if you want to have multiple software (like redis etc) in the docker container, then you can have docker compose file with content similar to this

```
  mongo:
    image : mongo
    ports : 
      - "<your_mongodb_port>:27017"
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports: 
      - "<your_redis_port>:6379"
```

ports configuration is optional

`docker-compose up` will bring up both mongo db and redis.

Comment: That's it!! i already find out and i wanted to post the solution but you did it first :) yeah docker-compose it's the best solution cause i have one mongo instance, one redis instance and a node + express app conencting to that mongo instance and all mapping with the ports i want just amazing

Comment: nice @FernandoDelOlmo .. keep rocking with docker

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that Docker is not meant to be a full VM replacement. In your case, you have to explicitly mention to run systemd - but your starting point is `/bin/bash`.

So I would advise you to change the starting point like `/usr/bin/mongod`. It's also a good idea to separate apps - so there's a container for Mongo, another for Redis etc - that's the purpose behind LXC/Docker.

You should also read more and get a deeper understanding of Docker to understand and appreciate the philosophy before venturing out to containerize apps and start distribution.

Hope it helps and all the best!

Comment: thank you a lot, but my task its to build an image with full env, node,mongo,redis.... reading your answer i start thinking its not possible

Comment: Well you can..there's nothing stopping you, but it's not advised. You can containerize different apps and use Docker "data volumes" to access persistent data across containers - read more about it.